# get duplicate values index using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

Say I have an array like this: `["a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "a"]`

I need to know which value is duplicated in what index.

In this case that indexes 0, 1 and 5 has the "a" value duplicated and indexes 3 and 4 has the "c" value duplicated.

Comment: What should the output look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Lodash:

```
import * as _ from "lodash";

let arr = ["a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "a"];

let result = _.omitBy(
  _.reduce(arr, (a, v, i) => _.set(a, v, (a[v] || []).concat([i])), {} ),
  v => v.length <= 1
);

console.log(result); // ​​​​​{ a: [ 0, 1, 5 ], c: [ 3, 4 ] }​​​​​
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach of ES6 and lodash. We use the [*.pickBy*](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#pickBy) and [.set](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#set) from lodash and ES6 for the rest:

```js
const data = ["a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "a"]

const result = _.pickBy(data.reduce((r,c,i,a) => a.indexOf(c, i) >= 0 ? _.set(r, c, [...r[c] || [], i]) && r : r, {}), x => x.length > 1)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The idea is to reduce and create an object with all properties having an array as value which indicates the indexes found. Then simply pick those props which their value length is bigger than 1.

Answer (score 0):

In plain Javascript you can do something like this:

```js
var arr = ["a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "a"];
var sort = [];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
 
  var index = sort.find(function(x){
   return x.Key == arr[i];
  });
  
   
  if(index != undefined && index.Indexes != undefined){
     sort.find(function(x){
     if(x.Key == arr[i]){
          x.Indexes.push(i);
        }
     })
  }else{
     sort.push({ Key: arr[i], Indexes: [i] });
  }

}

console.log(sort);
```

---

And if you want to wrap it into a function that accepts a single char and and retrieves the indexes for the specific char:

```js
var arr = ["a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "a"];

Array.prototype.GetAllIndexesFor = function(char){
   
var sort = [];
var arr = this;

  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

    if(arr[i] == char){
      sort.push(i);
    }

  }
return sort;
}

var indexesForA = arr.GetAllIndexesFor('a');
var indexesForB = arr.GetAllIndexesFor('b');
var indexesForC = arr.GetAllIndexesFor('c');

console.log(indexesForA)
console.log(indexesForB)
console.log(indexesForC)
```

Comment: Was tagged as javascript so here's a javascript solution.

Answer (score -1):

I realized what you need:

```js
let arr = ["a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "a"]
let o = {}

arr.forEach((e, i) => {
  // if you need only duplicates
  if (arr.indexOf(e) - arr.lastIndexOf(e) === 0)
    return
    
  (o[e] = o[e] || []).push(i)
})

console.log(o)
```

Comment: you're not using lodash

Comment: I will be surprised if using lodash there will be less code than mу